# How to change the order of elements (radio buttons) returned by jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with radio buttons.

In a jQuery collection, as `c = $('input[name=mybuttons]')`, I get them by rows, so that `c[0]` is the one in the top left cell.

How do I change this order, so that, say, `c[0]` be some another cell, or arrow keys go, say, by columns and not by rows; so that tab brings to some specific button rather than top left, and so that right arrow traverse the buttons in some specific order and not left-to-right?

For checkboxes and tab key, I achieve this with `tabindex`. How to achieve a similar effect for radio buttons and the right key: specify in HTML in what order the right key should traverse them?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2u30u7fp/3/ The tab key does iterate in the desired order, but the right and left keys don't.

Comment: `$('...')` will get you elements in the order they appear in the DOM. You cannot change this. You can sort them later according to some other condition; but your question would need to be much more specific (ideally including a JSFiddle). Also, behaviour of arrow keys has nothing to do with the behaviour of `$('...')`.

Comment: @Amadan Isn't it that tab gets you to `c[0]` and then right arrow gets you to `c[1]`, then `c[2]`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, since both go by DOM order. Change the DOM order to change both.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "arrow keys"? That sounds like you're looking for `tabindex` indeed.

Comment: @Bergi: At least in Chrome, tabs move between radios of different names, and arrows within radios of a same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are: use [.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) or `.insertAfter()`. In my example, if you choose a radio button, that button will go to first in the group.

```js
$(document).on("change", "input[name='sex']", function() {
  var index = $("input[name='sex']").index($(this));
  console.log(index);
  if (index != 0) {
    $(this).parent('div').insertBefore("div:first");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can't this be done in HTML? I added a fiddle to the question: http://jsfiddle.net/2u30u7fp/1/

Comment: @asker: You can get [MINE](http://jsfiddle.net/hungndv/zg6dsx46/1/). Do anything as you like. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), since you essentially have a list of elements once you've got `c`.

`var sortedC = _.sortBy(c, function (elem) { return elem.propertyToSort; });`

Comment: Thank you! The question was not how to sort an array in JavaScript, but rather how to specify the DOM order in HTML, so that tab would bring to some specific button, and the right arrow will traverse the buttons in some specific order. With checkboxes I do it with tabindex, how to I achieve a similar effect for a group of radio buttons? I will edit my question now.